# How to print character just after a particular character in a string using bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, scripting

I have a string like

```
abc def 0/1 dls dl 9/0 1//o
```

I want to take `0` and `1` (the characters just after and before the first `/` in the string) into two variables, say `$NUM1` and `$NUM2`, and do some further logic on them.

Comment: Take a look at the parameter expansion operators: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: i thought another use of stackoverflow is to help others solve the same general problem faster. I believe all the problems are made to be solved. quoting everyone has to stand on the shoulders of giants to look further

Comment: No, that's not how SO is supposed to be used. Read the help pages.

Comment: But i see a lot of similar questions, so asked.

Comment: I also see lots of similar questions, and I vote to close them.

Comment: thanks you for your services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ str='abc def 0/1 dls dl 9/0 1//o'
$ num1=${str%%/*}    # Remove first "/" and everything after it
$ echo "$num1"
abc def 0
$ num1=${num1##* }   # Remove last space and everything before it
$ echo "$num1"
0
$ num2=${str#*/}     # Remove first "/" and everything before it
$ echo "$num2"
1 dls dl 9/0 1//o
$ num2=${num2%% *}   # Remove first space and everything after it
$ echo "$num2"
1
```

`#`, `##`, `%` and `%%` have to be used carefully here. A single repetition removes the shortest match of the pattern following, and the double usage removes the longest pattern match.

---

Alternatively, after the first expansion, you just want the first or last character of the string, which can be solved with substring expansion:

```
$ echo "$num1"
abc def 0
$ echo "${num1:(-1)}"  # Extract last character
0
$ echo "$num2"
1 dls dl 9/0 1//o
$ echo "${num2:0:1}"   # Extract first character
1
```

Negative indices requires at least Bash 4.2. For older Bash versions, we can use

```
echo "${num1:${#num1}-1}"
```

---

And finally, we could use Bash regular expressions, as demonstrated in [glenn jackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46574492/3266847).

Comment: Yes, being not good at regular expressions, i found your answer the easiest to understand. Thanks again

Comment: @ParantapSharma Notice that these are not regular expressions: they are shell patterns (or "globs").

Comment: You can also use substrings: `num1=${str%%/*}; echo ${num:(-1):1}; num2=${str#*/}; echo ${num2:0:1}`

Comment: Sorry, didn't know the term for them

Comment: @glennjackman True, I kind of mentally assumed that all characters between the `/` the next space were supposed to be captured, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Benjamin W ,  Thanks for pointing out the minor glitch. and @glennjackman i was referring to the regular expressions used in sed tool's command in other answers in which i was having difficulty understanding, was not referring to your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash regular expressions, which populate the `BASH_REMATCH` array with the captured subexpressions:

```
if [[ $a =~ (.)/(.) ]]; then
  num1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  num2=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
echo $num1 $num2
```

```
0 1
```

Don't get into the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES: one day you'll accidentally write `PATH=/my/path` and then wonder why your script is broken. Leave upper case variables for the shell & OS

Comment: Thank you for your answer and thank you for the valuable advice about the variable naming too. Will follow that from now on in my scripts.

Comment: No, I think it was pretty easy and clean to read even for a non scripter. The first way i thought was actually to iterate till i see a / and store the location in a var and then truncate till there. I knew that would have been very inefficient and hence asked for advice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed to parse the line with regex to extract the numbers:

```
NUM1=$(echo 'abc def 0/1 dls dl 9/0 1//o' | sed 's@[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)/[0-9]*.*@\1@')
NUM2=$(echo 'abc def 0/1 dls dl 9/0 1//o' | sed 's@[^0-9]*[0-9]*/\([0-9]*\).*@\1@')
echo $NUM1
0
echo $NUM2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are implicitly separating characters based on spaces.  So you want the characters from the space to the first '/' and from the first '/' to the next space.  I would probably use sed:

```
echo "abc def 0/1 dls dl 9/0 1//o" | sed -r 's%^[^/]* ([^ ]*)/([^ ]*) .*%\1 \2%'
```

But note this won't work if there are no spaces preceding the first '/'.  You may wish to have another pattern for that case.